# Basic setup for glfw causes a runtime error with regards to eventlistener in emscripten generated js file

Tags: javascript, c++, canvas, glfw, emscripten

To make a long story short I tried to create the simplest possible setup for a an opengl c++ demo and the problem I have seems to be related to the
the initialization of the canvas with regards to the eventlistener that is found in the javascript wrapper for the wasm file. I'm new to this so I'll just post 
the code in cpp, the html file, and the command line used to compile the project plus the error in chromium.

This is the glfw.cpp

```
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
using namespace emscripten;

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES3

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>


void initialize()
{
 // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {

        EM_ASM_({
          console.log(' failed: ');
        }, 0);  
    }

    EM_ASM_({
      console.log(' end initialization: ');
    }, 0);  
}
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(glfw) 
{   
    function("initialize", &initialize);
}
```

This is the glfw.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" style = "height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color:red;"></canvas>
    <script>    
        var Module = 
        {
            canvas: function() 
            {
                console.log("canvas");
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(e) { alert('WebGL context lost. You will need to reload the page.'); e.preventDefault(); }, false);

                return canvas;
            },
            onRuntimeInitialized: function() 
            {
                Module.initialize();
            }               
        };  
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="glfw.js"> </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

the command to compile the project

emcc --bind -o glfw.js glfw.cpp -s USE_GLFW=3

and this is the complete error from the console.log in chromium

```
glfw.js:1645 Fetch finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/glfw.wasm".
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1645
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.js:1650 wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Module.canvas.addEventListener is not a function
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1650
Promise.catch (async)
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1647
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.js:1651 falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1651
Promise.catch (async)
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1647
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.js:1560 Fetch finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/glfw.wasm".
getBinaryPromise @ glfw.js:1560
instantiateArrayBuffer @ glfw.js:1633
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1652
Promise.catch (async)
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1647
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.js:5228 Assertion failed: the Module object should not be replaced during async compilation - perhaps the order of HTML elements is wrong?
glfw.js:5229 Assertion failed: the Module object should not be replaced during async compilation - perhaps the order of HTML elements is wrong?
abort @ glfw.js:5229
assert @ glfw.js:434
receiveInstantiatedSource @ glfw.js:1628
Promise.then (async)
instantiateArrayBuffer @ glfw.js:1635
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1652
Promise.catch (async)
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1647
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.js:1636 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: abort("Assertion failed: the Module object should not be replaced during async compilation - perhaps the order of HTML elements is wrong?") at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1033:13)
    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1050:12)
    at abort (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:5239:44)
    at assert (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:434:5)
    at receiveInstantiatedSource (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1628:7)
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1636
Promise.catch (async)
instantiateArrayBuffer @ glfw.js:1635
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1652
Promise.catch (async)
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1647
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.js:5228 abort("Assertion failed: the Module object should not be replaced during async compilation - perhaps the order of HTML elements is wrong?") at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1033:13)
    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1050:12)
    at abort (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:5239:44)
    at assert (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:434:5)
    at receiveInstantiatedSource (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1628:7)
glfw.js:5229 abort("Assertion failed: the Module object should not be replaced during async compilation - perhaps the order of HTML elements is wrong?") at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1033:13)
    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1050:12)
    at abort (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:5239:44)
    at assert (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:434:5)
    at receiveInstantiatedSource (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1628:7)
abort @ glfw.js:5229
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1637
Promise.catch (async)
instantiateArrayBuffer @ glfw.js:1635
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:1652
Promise.catch (async)
doNativeWasm @ glfw.js:1647
Module.asm @ glfw.js:1735
(anonymous) @ glfw.js:4813
glfw.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) abort("abort(\"Assertion failed: the Module object should not be replaced during async compilation - perhaps the order of HTML elements is wrong?\") at Error\n    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1033:13)\n    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1050:12)\n    at abort (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:5239:44)\n    at assert (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:434:5)\n    at receiveInstantiatedSource (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1628:7)") at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1033:13)
    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1050:12)
    at abort (http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:5239:44)
    at http://localhost:8080/glfw.js:1637:9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reverse engineer a working example and base my answer on it so this is the working code below that compiles fine and doesn't give any errors, just two warnings from the JavaScript file.

emcc -std=c++11 glfw.cpp -o glfw.js  -s USE_WEBGL2=3 -s FULL_ES3=3 -s USE_GLFW=3 -s WASM=3

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Emscripten-Generated Code</title>
    <style>
      body 
      {
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0;
        padding: none;
      }

      .emscripten { padding-right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; }
      div.emscripten { text-align: center; }      
      div.emscripten_border { border: 1px solid black; } 
      canvas.emscripten { border: 0px none; background-color: black; }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"></canvas>
    <script type='text/javascript'>     

      var Module = 
      {        
        canvas: (function() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');      
          canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(e) { alert('WebGL context lost. You will need to reload the page.'); e.preventDefault(); }, false);

          return canvas;
        })()
      };    

    </script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="glfw.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The bind.h isn't really needed except for an error with the namespace if it's not included.

```
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES3
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
using namespace emscripten;

int main()
{
 // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {

        EM_ASM_({
          console.log(' failed: ');
        }, 0);  
    }

    EM_ASM_({
      console.log(' end initialization: ');
    }, 0);  

    return 0;
}
```